# Multiple query for redis lists

Tags: ruby, redis

I have next situation: I have a lot of keys in redis. It stored as `string` type before. So I had to take values like:

`MGET key_1 key_2 ... key_n`.

In fact I use ruby script with `redis` gem but I think easy to explain question on 'raw' queries.
Anyway now these keys stored in the database as `list`. And it's now harder to collect all the values because I need to do *n* queries - by one for each list:

`LRANGE key_1 0 -1`,`LRANGE key_2 0 -1`
and so on.

It spend a lot of time and smells bad.
Probably someone can recommend something better?

Thanks

**UPD**

@ItamarHaber and @rchang properly made a remarks in comments. Thanks.

For more information I will explain some details about application where I use this on some concert example: I have dashboard for controlling deployment of applications. History of versions for each application stored exactly in redis as `list`(something like `application_1::history`, `application_2::history`). In form I have dropdown inputs with these versions. Each application has own history of installed versions.

So for filling dashboard form I need to take values from all these keys(I mean `history` keys). It should be in the end something like multiple arrays(like arrays in array) - main is `individually accessed` arrays and not collapsed all values into one big array. And I need always whole range of values from each key. Now it seems like broken bicycle and spend much time if I work with ~100 keys:

```
values = []
keys = ["application_1::history", "application_2::history"]
keys.each do |k|
  values << $redis.lrange(k, 0, -1)
end
```

**UPD**

I guess this question hasn't solutions. One variant which that can alleviate the situation and it might be worth a try - `pipelining`.

But I think best solution will be change type of storing data: like json as `string` type. `String` keys easy to take by `MGET` command and json easy to parse.

Comment: So why not move back to strings? If you'll expand your question to include more information about the data and what you're trying to do with it, perhaps someone can assist further...

Comment: +1 on the suggestion from @ItamarHaber to get more information on your use case.  Can all of your lists be collapsed into one, or is it imperative that they can be individually accessed?  Are you always going to retrieve the entirety of a particular list, or will you have to do something like `LRANGE key_2 5 10` from times to time?  Do you have significant amounts of memory headroom to potentially play with?